# Updating High Sierra installation is not progressing further

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, macos

I'm updating OS X EL Capitan to High Sierra.

Today morning I was go on App store and download High Sierra. After downloaded the installer opens automatically and I clicked on "Continue". [From apple's official document.](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201475)

But last 3-4 hours my installation process is stuck mean not progressing further.

[image]

So what can I Do? Why this is taking to much time? Should I cancel and restart the system and again try to install it? Or keep patience?

If I cancel and restart system and try again then I will be make any major problem? I don't know what I should do. Please guid me on right direction.

Comment: The need to press Cancel or hard reboot should be inversely proportional to the time since your last full backup.

Comment: If I will stop and reinstall again then any problem will occur or not?

Comment: You won't know until you try it, which is why you need to weigh the temptation against how recent your backup is.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for your guidance, successfully  installed High Sierra. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience:

Why this happening? Why my installation is not progressing further? Because issue is in my network. I connected my system with WiFi and sometimes signal comes with very low quality and in between installation for some second signal was lost and at that time installation is stopped/pushed. That was reason of installation is not progressing further.  But I tapped on **cancel** but even don't know what will happen! and restart my system and clicked again for installation. **It will not be started from begging but started from where we stopped/pushed.** Its really good things. And I was write comment like

> if we canceled installation and restart again then any major problem will occur?

Answer is **No** you can do cancel and reinstall process any time It will be managed by core system.